# Extra date from Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CSV file `Date` column with the following values:

```
StartDate
---------------------------
01/02/2014 0:00 
09/04/2013 0:00
```

I want to extract only the date part from the above column value. I created the table with data type as Varchar, because if I declare it as DATETIME then I am not able to perform a bulk insert.

Comment: Bulk-insert into a stage table with a varchar column, and then use SQL to CONVERT it to a datetime in your final destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Date part alone you can extract using LEFT function.
(provided all your data in the format as you specified above)

```
select LEFT(colname,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

get the date part by splitting by "space"

```
cols[col_num].split(" ")[0]
```

and then make insert statement.

Why the table has datatype varchar?? why not date?

Answer (score 0):

You can BULK INSERT into a table where you will keep the data for intermediary storage. Try something like:

```
 SELECT id, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateCol, 103), 10) FROM temptbl
```

Take a look at the following MSDN page for date formats available to you with CONVERT():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx